# rangy underline, bold or italy on chrome loose selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, rangy

On an editable content, I had place 3 buttons on top: B, I, U

On Firefox it works ok, but on Chrome, it seems that the selection is lost on click, before I arrive to the function on the event.

```
<i class="fa-bold">B</i>
<div contenteditable="true" id="theelement"></div>
<script>
$('.fa-bold').click(function (){
  var s = rangy.getSelection( document.getElementById('theelement') );
  var r = s.getRangeAt(0);

  rangy.createClassApplier('bold').toggleRange(r);
});
</script>
```

if you run it from console it works, if you click the button it doesn't, this only happens on Chrome, on FF from the button works ok.

Answer (score 0):

use mousedown instead of click as the event to prevent the bold button from getting the focus and this losing the focus. You may need to grab the event from the listening function so you can preventDefault behavior.